# Very quick question about random variables (Formal writing).

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I've came across this confusion while reading this question:

> The time until Sam receives his first email is exponentially distributed with parameter $4$. 
> The time between the first email and the second email, given that the first email has arrived in time $y$, is exponentially distributed with expectation of $y$.

So, by reading through the question, I wrote on the side $Y$- The times until the first email arrives $\Longrightarrow Y\sim Exp(4)$. 
And $X$- time between both emails. 
But was confused of how to write the second sentence, I know that $X|Y=y$ should be distributed with parameter $\lambda=\frac{1}{y}$, 
but how should it be written? 
$X|Y\sim Exp(\frac{1}{y})$ or $X|Y=y \sim Exp(\frac{1}{y})$. 
My intuition leans toward the second choice, but I know that $X|Y=y$ is a function of $y$, say $g(y)$, and that is not a random variable, so I'm not sure if I could write it like that. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is a function of $y$, but it's valued in random variables. That is, for each $y_0$, $g(y)$ is the random variable $X|Y=y_0$. Similarly, $\mathop{Exp}(\frac{1}{y})$ is a function of $y$ valued in random variables

Comment: @Jackson Thank you, would you say it's wrong to write $X|Y \sim exp(\frac{1}{y})$?

Comment: I'm not confident enough in my knowledge of statistics conventions to make this an answer, but I think so. It doesn't look right to me, but I don't know whether I'd say $X|Y$ is nonsense or if it's a random variable in its own right—in either case I don't think it means the same thing as $X|Y=y$, so I think it's wrong. But at the very least $X|Y=y$ is clearer